# Where did the cell label go?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've created my own class for showing a spreadsheet-like layout. I would like to enqueue and dequeue UITableViewCells. I use this code to do this:

```
- (void) enqueueReusableCell: (ABTableViewCell *) cell {    

if (!enqueuedCells[cell.reuseIdentifier])
    enqueuedCells[cell.reuseIdentifier] = cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier { 
ABTableViewCell *cell;

if (enqueuedCells[identifier]) {
    cell = enqueuedCells[identifier];

    return cell.tableViewCell;
}

return nil;
}
```

(I have a wrapper class that I am using to hold the UITableViewCell when enqueuing to store some additional data)

The problem is that when I dequeue the cell and try to access a sub-view, I don't get anything back. The following line returns a nil object after my cell has been dequeued.

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
```

This is using ARC on XCode 4.5.x. Any ideas?

Full source is here https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABTableView/
(dequeue just returns nil for now to avoid problem)

Comment: Are you ever actually `alloc`'ing the label?

Comment: The cell is originally pulled from a nib.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sub-classing UITableViewCell.  I don't see the advantage or sense in having a wrapper class owning a UITableViewCell ivar/property.  Just subclass UITableViewCell and add your extended properties/functionality.

Comment: Okay... refactored my code to use ABTableViewCell everywhere and updated my nibs to use ABTableViewCell in place of the default UITableViewCell. Still get a nil label object from dequeued cells.